# XML to Html table

Tags: html, xml, html-table

I trying to get my XML file called: lista.xml to my content.html. I read that there are many ways to done it in php in js, but I also read about simple way in html. Here is what I made:

**lista.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="style.css"?>
<spis>
    <lotnisko>
        <nazwa>Port Lotniczy Warszawa-Okęcie</nazwa>
        <kraj>Polska</kraj>
        <miasto>Warszawa</miasto>
        <rok>1934</rok>
    </lotnisko>

    <lotnisko>
        <nazwa>Port lotniczy Poznań-Ławica</nazwa>
        <kraj>Polska</kraj>
        <miasto>Poznań</miasto>
        <rok>1913</rok>
    </lotnisko>

    <lotnisko>
        <nazwa>Port lotniczy Gdańsk im. Lecha Wałęsy</nazwa>
        <kraj>Polska</kraj>
        <miasto>Gdańsk</miasto>
        <rok>1974</rok>
    </lotnisko>

    <lotnisko>
        <nazwa>Port lotniczy Wrocław-Strachowice</nazwa>
        <kraj>Polska</kraj>
        <miasto>Wrocław</miasto>
        <rok>1992</rok>
    </lotnisko>

    <lotnisko>
        <nazwa>Port lotniczy Barcelona</nazwa>
        <kraj>Hiszpania</kraj>
        <miasto>Barcelona</miasto>
        <rok>1918</rok>
    </lotnisko>

    <lotnisko>
        <nazwa>Port lotniczy Moskwa-Szeremietiewo</nazwa>
        <kraj>Rosja</kraj>
        <miasto>Moskwa</miasto>
        <rok>1959</rok>
    </lotnisko>

    <lotnisko>
        <nazwa>Port lotniczy Narita</nazwa>
        <kraj>Japonia</kraj>
        <miasto>Tokio</miasto>
        <rok>1978</rok>
    </lotnisko>
    <lotnisko>
        <nazwa>Port lotniczy Tajpej-Taiwan Taoyuan</nazwa>
        <kraj>Tajwan</kraj>
        <miasto>Taoyuan</miasto>
        <rok>1979</rok>
    </lotnisko>
    <lotnisko>
        <nazwa>Port lotniczy Memmingen</nazwa>
        <kraj>Niemcy</kraj>
        <miasto>Monachium</miasto>
        <rok>1936</rok>
    </lotnisko>

    <lotnisko>
        <nazwa>Port lotniczy Atlanta - Hartsfield-Jackson</nazwa>
        <kraj>Stany Zjednoczone</kraj>
        <miasto>Atlanta, Georgia</miasto>
        <rok>1926</rok>
    </lotnisko>
</spis>
```

**Here is html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

<XML ID="lista" SRC="lista.xml"></XML>
<table DATASRC="#lista">
    <thead>
    <th>Name</th><th>Country</th><th>City</th><th>Year</th>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td><SPAN DATAFLD="nazwa"></SPAN></td>
        <td><SPAN DATAFLD="kraj"></SPAN></td>
        <td><SPAN DATAFLD="miasto"></SPAN></td>
        <td><SPAN DATAFLD="rok"></SPAN></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

But the html file in browser is empty

Comment: Had you used `<tbody>` instead of the second `<thead>`, you would have got the data displayed in IE9 or earlier. But IE dropped support for it in IE10 and the other browsers have never supported this.

Comment: You were right. Thanks. Only ways to make it is PHP or JS now.